# How to put form validation in the model using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, validation, sqlalchemy, pyramid, wtforms

I see lots of apps using Form objects to validate data and then passing the data to the model, while putting absolutely no validation in the model. I feel it's better to put core validation in the model itself (e.g., no users under the age of 18, ever) to be run regardless of the context. In other words, I don't care how the user is being created (whether through web ui or command line), the core rules should always apply.

I'm using SQLAlchemy (within a Pyramid application), and I would like to define my core validation rules within the model in a way that my forms (WTForms) always respect the core rules defined in the model so that all data is consistent.

Is anybody else already doing this, or something similar?

Something similar to [this php](http://mwop.net/blog/200-Using-Zend_Form-in-Your-Models.html) solution.

Comment: couldn't you override whatever get/put/save/create methods you are using on your model in the model class itself (since they should always take precedence), then just use `super` to do the actual creation/update if it passes the tests?

Comment: One of the reason why it's good not to put validation in the model is that you might have different forms. One funny example would be to save an incomplete model. If you try to save an incomplete model, your model validation will fail, but if you have validation in your forms. One form might fail or pass but the final result will always be valid. Having validation in models make you do some ugly things like conditional validation... Keep in mind that model shouldn't contain any logic.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix Very good point, but I'm only considering core rules, which prevent saving an incomplete/corrupt model. For instance, "every user in the database must be of valid age, no exceptions". I feel as though a rule with this caliber of importance should reside in the model and serve as a final wall of defense if you will.

Comment: @JeffTratner Something along those lines, but I also want to be able to use those validation rules outside of the model, for example, in a registration form, where I would also need extra fields such as an EULA or a password confirmation field. I'd like to know if anybody else has already crossed this bridge.

Comment: @BDuelz I worked on a project with rails and one thing that disgust me the most is that all the logic about validation is in the model. For example, a password shouldn't be null. Seems fair enough but as soon as you want to enable registration with facebook or openid etc, you hit the wall because the password can actually be null but it can't be null if there is no openid... and by that you end up with really strange validation. Having validation in forms means that for any of your form, the saved model will be valid. Though it might be incomplete but form validation will always have to pass.

Comment: Other point, when a form doesn't pass validation, it will be possible to display errors for that form. If you try to save a model and the model doesn't pass the `model` validation. It is possible that the error can't be mapped to the form. In other word, it will be pretty hard to tell the user what didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLAlchemy allows you to register listeners, which are invoked when certain events occur, for example you can register an event  to be triggered when a model's field is modified. From [SQLAlchemy documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_7/orm/events.html):

> Listeners have the option to return a possibly modified version of the
>   value, when the retval=True flag is passed to listen():
>
> ```
> def validate_phone(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
>     "Strip non-numeric characters from a phone number"
>
>     return re.sub(r'(?![0-9])', '', value)
>
> # setup listener on UserContact.phone attribute, instructing
> # it to use the return value 
> listen(UserContact.phone, 'set', validate_phone, retval=True)
> ```
>
> A validation function like the above can also raise an exception such
>   as `ValueError` to halt the operation.

So, as you see, you can either modify or reject values for certain field at the model level.

I'm not sure if your form library integrates with this feature, but it definitely should not be too difficult to roll your own solution.

Comment: What about [@validates](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapper_config.html#simple-validators) ?

Comment: @Zitrak: The link has changed, it's now http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/mapped_attributes.html#simple-validators